# Installing Docker on Arch Linux - 404 error from url

Tags: docker, installation, archlinux

I have probably missed something obvious here but anyway... I am trying to install docker on arch linux (manjaro).

```
sudo Pacman -S docker
```

gives me the following:

```
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (4) bridge-utils-1.6-3  containerd-1.2.5-1  runc-1.0.0rc6-1  docker-1:18.09.3-1

Total Download Size:    36.72 MiB
Total Installed Size:  285.39 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] Y
:: Retrieving packages...
error: failed retrieving file 'runc-1.0.0rc6-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.tuchola-dc.pl : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'runc-1.0.0rc6-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.inode.at : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'runc-1.0.0rc6-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from ftp.nluug.nl : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'runc-1.0.0rc6-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from linorg.usp.br : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'runc-1.0.0rc6-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from ct.mirror.garr.it : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'runc-1.0.0rc6-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from manjaro.dcc.uchile.cl : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'runc-1.0.0rc6-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'runc-1.0.0rc6-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.0x.sg : The requested URL returned error: 404
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed retrieving file 'docker-1:18.09.3-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.tuchola-dc.pl : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'docker-1:18.09.3-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.inode.at : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'docker-1:18.09.3-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from ftp.nluug.nl : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'docker-1:18.09.3-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from linorg.usp.br : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'docker-1:18.09.3-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from ct.mirror.garr.it : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'docker-1:18.09.3-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from manjaro.dcc.uchile.cl : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'docker-1:18.09.3-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'docker-1:18.09.3-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from mirror.0x.sg : The requested URL returned error: 404
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed to commit transaction (unexpected error)
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

Any clues would be very welcome. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12):

Fixed it.

I needed:

```
sudo pacman -Syy docker
```

which first updates the repos.
Oops.

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same issue. I resolved it using

```
sudo pacman -Syy docker
```

The file isn't there because you're trying to get it probably from an older version. So you need to refresh them.

**-y** downloads a fresh copy of the master package database from the server(s) defined in **pacman.conf(5)**. This should typically be used each time you use    **--sysupgrade** or **-u**. Passing two **--refresh** or **-y** flags will force a refresh of all package databases, even if they appear to be up-to-date.